# NAT works in 1 browser but not another?

Tags: firewall, nat, google-chrome

I have a NAT policy translating a public IP to a private one so users can access sharepoint remotely.

I get sharepoint if I go in through Chrome - but nowhere else. My other users can't get it at all. Why would this work in only 1 browser and none others? It's not cached either - no logins are cached either. It's like I'm a new user accessing it from the internet. Sames true in Safari, which doesn't load.

The firewall doesn't state it's rejecting it. So it's atleast getting through the firewall.

The NAT policy does translate https:// ip (port TCP443) to port TCP444.

Comment: I have a sonicwall BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a proxy set up on a client machine that a web browser is honoring but another browser isn't? We've had the system settings for the proxy stop some program updates and IE, but firefox had to be independently set.

Is there any logging on the Sharepoint server or firewall that can show if and where the connections are attempted? You should at least see the attempt to hit the IP.

It would be helpful if you were able to find logging points for each attempt at the connection. If you run a packet sniffer on your system when you attempt to connect with Chrome and then IE, for example, you should see the packets attempting to connect to the correct IP. If they're both going out on the client correctly, then check logs on the entrance point of your network to see if the packets are arriving, then the sharepoint server to see what is connecting (if anything) to that.

Comment: Authentication is needed. I'll do some packet logging. However, accessing it internally on the private IP works fine, on the same port (TCP444). I'm not sure if that leads you to any more conclusions...

Comment: I monitored packets coming in at the firewall. From chrome it generated 2 packets and forwarded both requests. From safari it generated 1 and dropped the incoming request. What could this mean?

Comment: Drop code 37 at module 26= LICENSE drop @ network